# Is this the right way to import a pre-made database and open and close?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Ok, so i created a premade database using http://mobisys.in/blog/2012/01/tutorial-using-database-in-android-applications/ this tutorial right here. I've been getting errors about "Database not closed exception". and some errors going to my openDatabase. Is there anything wrong with my database class?

```
     public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

            //Open the database
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }

     //*Kalikot Delete pag may problema*//
        public DbHerbs openWritable()throws SQLException{
        //  ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
            myDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

        public DbHerbs openReadOnly()throws SQLException{
            myDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
            return this;
        }



     public void close() {
         if (myDatabase != null) {
          myDatabase.close();


         }
        // super.close();
        }
```

Here is how i open the class on the different fragments,

```
    private void openDb() {

    myDb = new DbHerbs(this.getActivity());
    try {

       myDb.createDataBase();

       } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
       }

        try {

           myDb.openReadOnly();

        }catch(SQLException sqle){

         throw sqle;

         }

     private void closeDb()
      {
        myDb = new DbHerbs(this.getActivity());
        myDb.close();
       }
```

And this is the error i get on the log cat.
http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4117/usgahftz_jpg.htm

Comment: You forgot to create the tables.

Comment: it's premade, the tables are already created, and the database is imported in the assets folder.

Comment: That's a lot of code, and it's not very well-organized... I'm having trouble following the program flow for a simple use-case. **EDIT**: Though it is 9am Monday here...

Comment: I wrote it all down just to be sure. xD the problem is the part where i open the database. xD not sure if that is correct.

Comment: if what you are looking for is a code review please post on the code review stack instead.

Comment: @e4c5 i actually have i lot of errors in the logcat. since the error stated that "Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here" i'm not sure if the real error is the database or the cursor. I'm not even sure if that is the right way of doing it.

Comment: Well if the error is telling you that you didn't close your cursor the sensible thing to do is to close it!

Comment: @e4c5 which it also points errors in my database. xD at line 166 on the database class.

Comment: And how is anyone supposed to find what is line 166 by counting ? As others have pointed out please post only the relevent sections.

Comment: Well said, my bad. xD didn't see that part. xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not closing the database here:

```
private void closeDb()
{
    myDb = new DbHerbs(this.getActivity());
    myDb.close();
}
```

You are replacing your existing instance of the database with a new one and closing that new one. The old one will be garbage collected while it's in the opened state. So in effect closeDb() doesn't do anything.

Why are you trying to create an instance of the database every time you need read access to it?

```
private void openDb() {

   myDb = new DbHerbs(this.getActivity());
   try {

      myDb.createDataBase();

   } catch (IOException ioe) {

      throw new Error("Unable to create database");
   }

   try {

       myDb.openReadOnly();

   }catch(SQLException sqle){

       throw sqle;

   }
```

If what you are trying to do is to copy across a pre made database that was placed in the assets folder, the recommended approach is to https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

When ever you need to read from or write to your db you should call [getReadableDatabase()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase()) and getWritableDatabase() on the SQLiteOpenHelper. You will find full working code in the android samples.

Comment: Thanks. :) helped alot, So on the oncreate of my mainactivity start, i only need to use open once? and only call the getReadableDatabase() and getWritableDatabase() using the instance that i created on the oncreate?